# Accessibility of Hamburger Menu?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, accessibility, screen-readers

I am currently working on making a responsive website accessible and I wonder whether a blind person who opens the page on a smartphone will be able to open the hidden menu somehow, or if he/she "sees" it anyway - read by the screen reader?

My "Hamburger menu" has a structure like this:

```
<div class="menu-icon">Click here to open or close the menu</div>
<nav id="navigation" role="navigation" tabindex="0" >
    <ul>
       <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
       <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
       <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
       <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
       <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The related CSS is as follows (first the general rules, then the media queries for mobile):

```
.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}
nav {
  display: block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-image: url(images/menu-icon.png);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    text-indent: -5000px;
  }   
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

And here's the relevant jQuery:

```
jQuery('.menu-icon').on('click', function () {
  jQuery('nav').slideToggle(300);
});
```

All this works as expected, but I am wondering how a mobile device with activated screen reader will present this to the user and let him/her control it:

- Will he/she be able to "click" the `.menu-icon` div somehow to ge
  access to the menu?

  If not, will the following CSS (which follows *after* the media
  queries for mobile) make the menu "visible" to the screenreader the
  same way as on a desktop screen?:

-

```
@media speech {
  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

I know some will say "just try it", but it's really hard to test if you are not used to handle a screenreader on a regular basis, especially on mobile (plus every screenreader acts a bit different...). The mobile simulation mode in the browser tools (on desktop) doesn't help here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to include a visually hidden text like 'open menu' in the element triggering the open (usually an `a` tag), and add the attribute `role="button"` to the trigger. Also the `a` tag href will be the anchor to the nav id.

```
<a href="#nav" role="button" class="js_open_trigger">open menu</a>
<nav id="nav">......</nav>
```

Then you would need media queries to show/hide the desktop or mobile parts.

Comment: I kind of had that already, but without the `button` role: My div `.menu-icon` apart from a background-image showing the icon also contains some text which is made invisible by `text-indent: -5000px`. But I now added `role="button"` and a `tabindex` to that DIV, and that way it's possible to focus it and "click" it using the according key combination (which wasn't before), which makes the menu visible. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I would also add an `aria-expanded` label to your menu button. In traditional screen readers, this information is relayed to the user letting him / her know the current state of the menu: expanded or collapsed. Also, if you stick with using the `<div>`, make sure you set its `role`, `type` and `tabindex`.

```
<div class="menu-icon" role="button" type="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">Click here to open or close the menu</div>
<nav id="navigation" role="navigation" tabindex="0" >
    ...
</nav>
```

You can then change the value of `aria-expanded` by modifying your existing jQuery code slightly:

```
jQuery('.menu-icon').on('click', function () {
    jQuery('nav').slideToggle(300)
    jQuery(this).attr('aria-expanded', function(i, attr) {
        // Returning whether the attribute is equal to false is the same as inverting it
        return attr === 'false'
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! But something is wrong, probably at my side: The jQuery addition should change the "aria-expanded" value of `.menu-icon`, right? But it doesn't when I try it. Hmm...

Comment: What is that `i` in the function parameters for?

Comment: Okay, found it: Has to be `jQuery(this).attr("aria-expanded", function(i, attr) { ... etc.` in the third line. Now it works.

Comment: You're right, sorry for the confusion! I'll correct it in my answer. But I'm glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Also, the `i` is the index position. You can read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

Answer (score 2):

You could add the `button` role on your div and a `tabindex` but the best thing is to use the `<button>` tag.

You also have to remove the `tabindex` from your `nav` and avoid giving the redundant `role="navigation"`

```
<button class="menu-icon">Click here to open or close the menu</button>
<nav id="navigation">
    <?php
        $arguments = array(
            'theme-location' => 'main menu',
            'container' => ''
        );
        wp_nav_menu($arguments);
    ?>
</nav>
```

The `@media speech` is useless. No actual screenreader use it.

Also, remember, that you should set the `aria-hidden` attribute on the `nav` depending if its visibility for assistive technologies which might access directly the dom.